# How to bind context to async storage using React Native

Tags: react-native, firebase-realtime-database, asyncstorage

I have a list of items. users can like them. 
I use AsynStorage to store the state. It works.
Only, I can't bind the storage to a specific item. If I like/dislike an item, the same thing happen for all of them. Here is the code, an idea ?

```
componentWillMount() {
  this._renderSwitchButtonWithAsyncStorage().done;
}

 _renderSwitchButtonWithAsyncStorage = async() =>  {
          let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('AlreadyLiked');

          if (token){
            this.setState({trueSwitchIsOn: true});

          }else{
            this.setState({trueSwitchIsOn: false});
          }
        }; 



onPressIcon(word){
              AsyncStorage.setItem('AlreadyLiked', JSON.stringify({trueSwitchIsOn}));
}
```

Comment: you would need to set a different 'key' that you pass in as a string for the first argument. that way when you set the value to something else it will only be affected for that key

Comment: @MattAft, could you please give me more details ? I have tried to pass (word), like so `onPressIcon(word){ AsyncStorage.setItem(JSON.stringify(word), JSON.stringify({trueSwitchIsOn}));` but could not make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Different AsyncStorage key name,
If you use same name to affect the all users so each users has use different key

Comment: Alright, very newbie at this, could you please give me more details ? I have tried to pass (word), like so `onPressIcon(word){
              AsyncStorage.setItem(JSON.stringify(word), JSON.stringify({trueSwitchIsOn}));` but could not make it work

Answer (score 1):

I got it, thank you:

```
onPressIcon(word){

              const { _key} = this.props.navigation.state.params;

              AsyncStorage.setItem(JSON.stringify({_key}),JSON.stringify({trueSwitchIsOn}));

//Check if token exists
 _renderSwitchButtonWithAsyncStorage = async() =>  {
              const {_key} = this.props.navigation.state.params;
              let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem(JSON.stringify({_key}));
```